# My Laravel 5 production website crashes but I can't make it crash when I navigate

Tags: php, laravel

This is the message I received from the email logs. I receive it 2 times. I check that the person was coming from facebook but when I try to reapeat it was no problem for me.

```
#0 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(652): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(214): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(101): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(115): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/xxx/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form my experience this happends when user visit url that don't have matching route.
You don't have route defined in routes.php for visited url.

Mybe following is the case:
if you have url:
www.ecample.com/image.gif
and route

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/{var}', ['as' =>'homepage','uses' => 'SiteController@index']);
```

if the image exists laravel will show image but if image doesn't exists route will be triggered if any match given url. If the image is small and imperceptible you won't notice error.

Comment: No is not that because I can navigate normally and still get the errors. but get that in email...